# Angular 2: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined for push notification

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular-components

Im trying to show a push notification on button click.

Im stuck with a angular promise error which says:

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

**Full error stack trace:**

> Uncaught Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:17:2 caused by: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at PushNotificationComponent.show (notification.component.js:42)
>       at DebugAppView.View_AppComponent0.handleEvent_16 (/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:129)
>       at DebugAppView.eventHandler (view.js:664)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.COMPONENT_REGEX (dom_renderer.js:489)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:367)
>       at Object.NgZone.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:366)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.cancelFn.invoke (zone.js:420)

I am using the the github link :

https://github.com/alexcastillo/ng2-notifications/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html

My **app.module.ts** is as:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { PushNotificationComponent } from 'ng2-notifications/src/app/components/notification.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PushNotificationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Directive,
  EventEmitter,
  OnInit,
  OnChanges,
  OnDestroy,
  Input,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';

import '../style/app.scss';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
 })
@Directive({
 selector: 'push-notification'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'ng2-notifications';
  description: string = 'Angular 2 Component for Native Push Notifications';

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<header>
    <h1 class="title">{{ title }}</h1>
</header>
<main>

    <h2>{{ description }}</h2>

    <img src="img/demo.gif">

    <push-notification #notification title="ng2-notifications" body="Native Push Notifications in Angular 2" icon="<some_ulr>" closeDelay="2000" (load)="notification.show()"> //Problem Here!!
    </push-notification>

    <button (click)="notification.show()">Show Notification</button>

</main>
```

If i remove the line:  `(load)="notification.show()` it seems fine, but it doesnt serve any purpose without a notification after button click!

Comment: why your AppComponent is decorated like a Component and then like a Directive

Comment: what is a directive doing in a component ?

Comment: Could yu please correct my file !

Answer (score 0):

Error is here:

Remove this code block from **app.component.ts**

```
@Directive({
 selector: 'push-notification'
})
```

Note :

> https://github.com/alexcastillo/ng2-notifications is coded with beta
>   version of angular, so find the newer version or different plugin.
>
> Given Doc is also regarding to the beta version of angular

Comment: add in module part , u mean to add @Directive({  in app.module.ts file?

Comment: PushNotificationComponent is already there , so don't worry , and try again

Comment: Could u pls eloborate on which file i have to modify, Should i have to create a file called: app.directive.ts and add the @Directive({
 selector: 'push-notification'
}) in that file?

Comment: the plugin you are using is very old , not compatible with current angular version

Comment: Any recent version for the same, or how can i correct the code to support the current version

Comment: Can u pls confirm if this is a stable version plugin: https://github.com/shibulijack/angular2-notifications-lite  and satisfies the new angular 2 folder structure?

Comment: Could you please tell how should my component.html should look like to display the notifications cause the new links documentations says nothing apart from the importing their class

Comment: its a service , that you have to inject and just call the function like this.pushService.create('Just a title') , http://flauc.github.io/angular2-notifications/

Comment: I saw the demo, but need to know like how to use the same in my html as i have used <push-notification, how to use it for the new link, could yu please show the full code in the component.html and .ts files

Comment: https://github.com/shibulijack/angular2-notifications-lite/blob/master/src/simple-notifications.component.ts

Comment: So should i have to use the same code in my app.component.ts as in simple-notifications.component.ts by changing the selector-id etc